# How do i place a word with backspace and word?

Tags: sed

I have a text file containing lines like:

```
telephone xxxx
telpassword xxxx
telephone xxxx
telpassword xxxx
telephone xxxx
telpassword xxxx
telephone xxxx
telpassword xxxx
telephone xxxx
telpassword xxxx
telephone xxxx
telpassword xxxx
```

and I want to make a file to contain same data but in lines:

```
telephone xxxx telpasswordxxxx
telephone xxxx telpasswordxxxx
telephone xxxx telpasswordxxxx
telephone xxxx telpasswordxxxx
telephone xxxx telpasswordxxxx
```

I tried:

```
sed 's/telpassword/\btelpassword/g'
```

but this command is not working. I think it should be something like this, but i can't figure out how to put there the "backspace" command.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

From [sed one liners](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt):

```
sed '$!N;s/\n/ /' inputfile
```

Using awk:

```
awk '!(NR%2){print p " " $0}{p=$0}' filename
```

Comment: Hello, 

the sed command is working , but i think that my file has some lines that are empty, can you adjust the sed command to have as string "telpassword" or "telephone" ?

Comment: Add `grep tel |` before the command.  Don't forget to add the `|`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
 awk '/tele/{printf "%s ",$0}/telp/{print $0}' inputFile
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [vim](/questions/tagged/vim)

Content of `script.vim`:

```
set backup
g/^telephone/ normal J
saveas! output.txt
q!
```

Run it like:

```
vim -u NONE -N -S script.vim infile
```

It will create a file `output.txt` with content:

```
telephone xxxx telpassword xxxx
telephone xxxx telpassword xxxx
telephone xxxx telpassword xxxx
telephone xxxx telpassword xxxx
telephone xxxx telpassword xxxx
telephone xxxx telpassword xxxx
```

Comment: Hello Birei, I am using solaris 8 and I don t have vim. Can you please

Comment: can you please adjust this script for .sh or .ksh ? Thanks

Comment: @VulturuStefan: Those are different things. Use solutions from other answers, either `sed` or `awk` are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use paste:

```
paste -d" " - - < filename
```